# How do you tell Google to not read the fragment as an article?

Tags: google-search-console, microformats

Using the Structured Data Tool in Google Webmaster Tools I have an error where Google says we are missing the required author, updated fields etc. for an entry that we do not want to have these fields.

Is there a way to tell Google that this is not an Item/Article?

Comment: Are you refering to schema.org, e.g., [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article)? So you have this markup, but you want Google to tell that it’s not there?

Comment: Google auto detects the content as http://microformats.org/profile/hentry also see here http://microformats.org/wiki/hentry . Google does not see it as the new h-entry. This is a html fragment on one of our pages, but I do not want to publish the meta info (author, updated) in this fragment. So, is there a way to tell google that it is not rich content?

Comment: Are you using hEntry as Microformat or as vocabulary for Microdata?

Comment: Not sure what is the difference at the moment. As Microformat I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way. Google recognizes that you are using it, and either reports that you are not using the Microformat correctly (in which case it’d be a "Microformat error", if there would be such a thing), or that it doesn’t suffice Google’s guidelines for displaying a Rich Snippet (in which case it would be no error, just a notice).

The Microformat [hEntry](http://microformats.org/wiki/hentry) *requires* `entry-title`, `updated`, and `author`. The Microformat [h-entry](http://microformats.org/wiki/h-entry) has [no required properties](http://microformats.org/wiki/h-entry#what_is_the_bare_minimum_list_of_required_properties_on_an_h-entry).